# reading number and character one after another until end of input in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, input, cin

suppose I have input like

```
1 2 34 4 58975 6
2 356 4 5 
3 77 5 89 1
```

now I want to read the input like first number 1 in a number variable and in a character variable[say. var] the space in between 1 and 2, next step it will decide whether var is equals to '\n' or not,if not then read again .this time it will read number 2 and the space in between 2 and 3.similar mannaer ,in last the number variable will read 6 and var will read '\n'.as var=='\n' ,I want my program to go next line and read again in the same manner.
and when the input reading is finished I want my program to terminate!!
I know how many lines are there in the input.
I want the c++ code of this program.
I myself made one but itz not working.
here is the code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char a;
int line =1,temp;
while(line<=3){
    while(1){
            cin>>temp>>a;
            if(a!='\n'){

        }else{

            break;
            }
        }
      ++line;
    }
   cout<<cnt;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try to build and run your code? In which way does it not satisfy your goal?

Comment: First of all, please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Then continue continue to read about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

Comment: In short, you don't need to to that explicit newline check. Your code could be made much more simple.

Comment: Please format your code consistently, preferably with an automatic tool. This makes it readable, which is required for understanding, which in turn is required for finding and fixing bugs.

Comment: I have input formatted in 200 lines of row but column number is changing in every row,thats why I'm facing problem while reading

Comment: [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c) solves this problem for a comma as a separator instead of a space. I'm sure you can adapt that code slightly.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::istringstream linestream(line);

        std::vector<int> all_integers_on_line(
            std::istream_iterator<int>(linestream),
            std::istream_iterator<int>());

        // Now the vector all_integers_on_line contains all integer values
        // on the current line. Do something useful with them...
    }
}
```

References:

- [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)
- [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)
- [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
- [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)